# CR LF notepad++ removal

Tags: notepad++

I am using notepad++ , after end of line when i press enter CR LF is printed . I tried a lot but not able to remove it . Please help me to change the setting so that I can restore it back and there wont be CR LF anyomre.

[image]

Answer (score 207, accepted):

View -> Show Symbol -> uncheck Show End of Line.

Comment: for latest notepad++ versions, go to View -> Show Symbol ->uncheck Show All Characters

Answer (score 29):

View -> Show Symbol -> uncheck Show All characters

Answer (score 23):

Goto View -> Show Symbol -> Show All Characters. Uncheck it. There you go.!!

[image]

Answer (score 4):

"View -> Show Symbol -> uncheck Show All characters" may not work if you have pending update for notepad++. So update Notepad++ and then 
View -> Show Symbol -> uncheck Show All characters

Hope this is helpful!

Answer (score 3):

The best and quick solution to the problem is first do this:
View-> Show Symbol-> uncheck Show End of Line

This will solve problem for 90% of you and as in my case CR LF and its combinations still persist in the code.
To fix this simply create a new tab using ctrl+n and copy whole file and paste in this new file. All CRLF gone, copy whole file again and go to original file delete whole code and paste the copied save and you rock!!!

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

[image]Goto View -> Show Symbol
Select as per screen-shot, you will get correct

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Answering questions here is encouraged, but this answer appears to just repeat information already in other answers. New answers to old questions that already have an accepted answer (the one from Piere that has a green tick) should provide new information and new insights on the topic.

Answer (score 0):

**Please find the below screenshot**

[image]

[image]