# How to disable EOL in notepad++

Tags: notepad++

I am trying to write code in notepad++ and when I press enter, it appends CTRL characters in the file.
How to remove that CTRL character from notepad++ settings?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CR LF notepad++ removal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41036033/cr-lf-notepad-removal)

Answer (score 0):

view->show symbol -> uncheck show all characters